# Combinational meaning of $\sum\limits_{k=r}^{n} {k \choose r }={{n+1} \choose r+1}$

Tags: combinatorics, summation

What's the combinational interpretation of the identity $\sum\limits_{k=r}^{n} {k \choose r }={{n+1} \choose r+1}$?

Comment: Just use induction and the identity: $$\binom{n}{k}=\binom{n-1}{k}+\binom{n-1}{k-1}.$$

Comment: I know how to prove it by induction but I need to undestand it's combinatorial interpretation.

Comment: Then count the number of subsets of $\{1,\ldots,n+1\}$ with $r+1$ elements according to the maximum element in them.

Comment: More details are given in http://math.stackexchange.com/a/357087/139123

Answer (score 2, accepted):

we want choose r+1 persons from n+1 persons
let A(1), A(2),..., A(n+1) are that n+1 persons
first we count the numbers of choices that A(1) is choosed that equals to (r,n)
second we count the numbers of choices that A(1) is not choosed but A(2) is choosed that equals to (r,n-1)
third...
and sum of these is equal to (r+1,n+1)