# Combinatorial proof for $\sum_{k = 0}^n \binom {r+k} k = \binom {r + n + 1} n$

Tags: combinatorics, summation, binomial-coefficients, combinatorial-proofs

I'm trying to figure out a combinatorial proof for:

$$\displaystyle \sum_{k \mathop = 0}^n \binom {r+k} k = \binom {r + n + 1} n$$

I've tried the committee counting thing, but that didn't work.

Comment: See http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/357063/proving-that-sum-k-0n-mk-choosem-mn1-choose-m1, http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/833451/prove-sum-i-0n-binomik-1k-1-binomnkk and other posts linked there.

Comment: This question asks specifically about combinatorial proofs: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1408642/combinatorial-proof-for-binomial-identity-sum-k-0n-binomkp-binom

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A combinatorial proof is by counting bit strings of length $r+n+1$ with exactly $n$ ones. There are $\binom{r+n+1}{n}$ such strings.

Such strings have $r+1$ zeros. Now count all bit strings of length $r+n+1$ with exactly $r+1$ zeros in which the last $0$ is at $(r+k+1)$-st position. Here $k \in \{0,1,\ldots,n\}$. There are exactly $\binom{r+k}{r} = \binom{r+k}{k}$ such strings. Since all possible positions for the last zero are $r+1, \ldots, r+n+1$, and since the sets of bit strings with the last zero at different positions are disjoint, this proves the given identity.